# Xmodmap doesn't work on Linux Mint 19

Tags: linux-mint, xmodmap

I am trying to run the command `xmodmap -e "keycode 37 = Pointer_Button3"` which should switch the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to right click mouse button. However, it doesn't work. Why?

I try to check the key event using "xev" here what it printed out

```
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
root 0x9f, subw 0x0, time 253460, (54,99), root:(477,388),
state 0x0, keycode 37 (keysym 0xfeeb, Pointer_Button3), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```